# comparing a number with a prefix in a class in python

Tags: python, class

I am working on a small module.

I have a class called pricelist. It contains the attributes prefix and price.

```
class pricelist:
    def setPrefix(self,prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix
    def setPrice(self,price):
        self.price = price
    def getPrefix(self):
        return self.prefix
    def getPrice(self):
        return self.price
    def getPrefixLength(self):
        return len(self.prefix)
```

I have created a list of pricelist objects.

now i want to perform the operation, where when i give a phone number as input, i want to find prefix of the number and the corresponding price related to the prefix.

Example:

```
prefix    price
46        2.0
44        3.0
.
.
.
.
```

when i give the input say "46 7223232323", it should return the price corresponding to it.
I am new to python and python classess, so can you please help me out with the logic of this

Comment: You really shouldn't be writing getters and setters like that in Python. Just access and set the attributes directly. If at some future time you actually need to add more code in there, Python has properties.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the prefixes and prices in a dict:

```
self.data = {"46":  2.0,"44":3.0}
inp =  "46 7223232323"
get_pre = inp.split()[0]
print (self.data.get(get_pre))
2.0

class Pricelist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {"46":  2.0,"44":3.0}

p = Price_list()
inp =  "46 7223232323"
get_pre = inp.split()[0]
print (p.data.get(get_pre,"Sorry that is an invalid prefix")) # if the prefix does not exist, it will output "Sorry that is an invalid prefix"
```

You can access attributes directly without getters and setters:

```
class Price_list:
    def __init__(self,prefix,price):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.price = price
        self.pre_len = len(self.prefix)
p = Price_list("46", "4.99")
print (p.prefix, p.price, p.pre_len)
```

You can use data as a class attribute and add all instance attributes to it:

```
class Price_list:
    data = {}
    def __init__(self, prefix, price):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.price = price
        self.pre_len = len(self.prefix)

p = Price_list("46", "4.99")
p.data[p.prefix] = [p.price]

p1 = Price_list("44", "3.99")
p1.data[p1.prefix] = [p1.price]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply... I am working on this logic...I will update you after i finish this logic

Comment: split_input = num.split()[0]
print split_input
for price_list_objects in op_objects.getPriceList():
            price_list_objects.get(split_input)

I have implemented this logic based on your code. But i get this error: ""AttributeError: CallPrice instance has no attribute 'get'""

can you tell me what should i do to solve this

Comment: what is `op_objects.getPriceList()`?

Comment: op_objects is a group of price list objects. This op_objects cotains two different price list. Simply to put, obj A contains a list of priceList objects, and obj B contains a list of pricelist objects and so on...

Comment: the get method is from the `dict` you need use `instance.data.get`

Comment: can i have your contact details so that we can chat about the problem that i am facing, ur skype id or facebook id. I can give you a breif explanation of the problems i am facing